Why is the torsion of a connection in the frame bundle of a manifold $0$ on vertical vectors?
I briefly recall the context of a connection on a frame bundle. Let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold, $p: Fr(M) \rightarrow M$ its frame bundle where a frame $z \in Fr(M)$ is seen as an isomorphism $z:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow T_x M$.
The fundamental form of this bundle is an $\mathbb R^n$-valued $1$-form $\theta \in \Omega^1(B(W), \mathbb R^n)$ defined by
$$
\theta(X_z) = z^{-1}(d_z p(X_z))
$$
i.e. it just gives the representation of the pushforward of a tangent vector in the frame $z$.
$\theta$ is equivariant with respect to the action of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ and $0$ on vertical vectors.
A connection in $B(W)$ is equivalent to the kernel of a $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb R)$-equivariant $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb R)$-valued $1$-form $\omega$ which sends fundamental vector fields to the elements in the Lie algebra which generate them.
Finally, the torsion of a connections $\omega$ is defined to be the $\mathbb R^n$-valued $2$-form
$$
\Sigma(X,Y) = d\theta(X,Y) + \omega(X)(\theta(Y)) - \omega(Y)(\theta(X))
$$
where $\omega(X)$ at a point is a linear transformation applied to the vector $\theta(Y)$ at a point. $\Sigma$ is written compactly as $\Sigma = d\theta + \omega \wedge \theta$.
I am trying to see why $\Sigma$ is $0$ if one of the arguments is vertical.
In that case, since $\theta$ vanishes on vertical vectors, if say $X$ is a vertical vector field and $Y$ is any vector field, we have also by Cartan's formula:
$$
\Sigma(X,Y) = - X(\theta^1(Y)) - \theta^1([X,Y]) + \omega(X)(\theta^1(Y))
$$
But I don't know what to do beyond this.

Have you looked in the standard textbooks, like Kobayashi-Nomizu?
